# Upload APNs to Firebase console fails - "There is no Team ID stored for this app"

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications

Trying to upload APNs file to firebase console.
Inserted Team ID and Key ID - Got "There is no Team ID stored for this app" (Although inserted):

Please advise
[image]

Answer (score 13):

It's simply a bug in Firebase Console.
Just refresh and you'll get the following:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Steps:

1. Go to **Firebase Project Settings**
2. Select the "**General**" tab
3. Select your iOS app and Enter Team ID. Refer to the image below.

[image]

After this step Team ID will automatically come while you upload APNs Auth Key.