# Firebase - I get the error "There is no Team ID stored for this app" when uploading the APNs authentication key

Tags: firebase, push-notification

I tried to upload my APNs auth key to Firebase to use notifications in my iOS app.
However, when I press the upload button, I get the error "There is no Team ID stored for this app".
I tried several times and the result was the same.
The Team ID is already registered in the iOS app.
How can I solve this problem?
Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61099195/upload-apns-to-firebase-console-fails-there-is-no-team-id-stored-for-this-app This is a similar question, but the answer here did not solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four days after I asked this question, I tried again and somehow the iOS team ID was removed. I re-saved and tried to upload the APNs auth key again, and it worked.

I'm not sure what caused it, but I assume it wasn't saved properly because the first time I saved the team ID, it behaved a little strangely.

If anyone else is in the same situation, re-saving the team ID may help.